# Get scandir system call to work properly for user-defined compare functions?

Tags: sorting, system-calls, scandir

I have a task to scan a dir and sort it according to several criterias like size, modified time, etc. Looking at man page of `scandir`, shows

```
 SYNOPSIS
   #include <dirent.h>

   int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
          int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
          int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

Accordingly, i have written a function pointer that sorts based on size of files. It's working perfect if the directory to scan is current directory ***only***. In the function pointer, since I get 2 dirent pointer, which doesn't hold the size parameter of the file/folder, I have done a `lstat`, to get the size information.

So, this works perfectly, if the directory given to scandir is current directory, but doesn't work for any other directory other than current, Because, for `lstat`, it needs the complete path to the file and obviously, it doesn't have the complete path, leading to error saying "No Such File or Directory" if the scandir is passed with a different path.

```
lstat((*d1)->d_name, &sb1);
lstat((*d2)->d_name, &sb2);
```

Hence, I would like to know how to use the function pointer (the 4th argument) and sort on based on size of file?

I can get the inode number from the dirent pointer, but there seems no way of finding a file details with just a inode number using only the system call. System library(exec) is not allowed.

Any hints?